# How to say a sequence is of $\mathcal O(k^3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, proof-writing, article-writing

I am wondering which one of the following statements are a more standard way of saying a sequence has cubic growth rate:

1. *The sequence $\lambda_k$ has cubic growth rate.*
2. *The growth rate of the sequence $\lambda_k$ is of cubic order.*
3. *The growth rate of the sequence $\lambda_k$ is cubic.*
4. *The sequence $\lambda_k$ is of order $\Theta(k^3)$.*

Comment: The first three aren’t really equivalent to the fourth: a constant sequence is $O(k^3)$. If you really mean that it has cubic growth rate, you probably want to say that it’s in $\Theta(k^3)$.

Comment: *The sequence $\lambda_{k}$ is $O(k^3)$ as $k$ tends to infinity.*  The notation "O" already indicates "upper bound", so it is clear that you are estimating the growth rate **from above** (i.e., it grows **no faster** than $k^3$).

See the section "Comparison of the asymptotic behavior of functions" in Zorich's *Mathematical analysis*.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used $\Theta$. Now which sentence is written better?

Comment: "is Theta(k^3)" is probably more common than "is Theta(k^3)".

Comment: @djechlin
what!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We write
>   \begin{align*}
> \lambda_k= O(k^3)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad k\rightarrow \infty
> \end{align*}
>   if the ratio $\lambda_k/k^3$ stays bounded as $k$ tends to $\infty$. In other words, there exists a $K\in\mathbb{N}$ and a constant $C>0$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
> |\lambda_k|\leq C| k^3|\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad k>K
> \end{align*}
>
> We say that
>
> - $\lambda_k$ is of **order at most** $k^3$ or
> - $\lambda_k$ is **big-Oh of** $k^3$ (as $k$ tends to $\infty$)

This wording is stated in the classic *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick in Appendix $A.2$ *Asymptotic notation* together with the definition and correct wording of further asymptotic symbols.

> - Note the big-Oh notation $O(k^3)$ is used whenever we want to state that a sequence $\lambda_k$ is bounded **from above** by a constant times $k^3$.
> - We use another notation $\Omega(k^3)$ when we want to say that the sequence $\lambda_k$ is bounded **from below** by a constant times $k^3$. This means that the sequence $\lambda_k$ is of order **at least** $k^3$.
> - If we can bound a sequence $\lambda_k$ from both sides, meaning it is both $O(k^3)$ as well as $\Omega(k^3)$ then we write $\lambda_k=\Theta(k^3)$ and say, $\lambda_k$ is order **exactly** $k^3$.

**Conclusion:**

- Point (1) to (3) do not precisely state that $\lambda_k$ is big-Oh of $k^3$ since the formulation bounded *from above* or an equivalent formulation is missing.
- Point (4) addresses with $\Theta(k^3)$ a different situation, namely $\lambda_k$ is both bounded from above as well as bounded from below by a constant times $k^3$.

*Hint:* Historical information around Big-Oh and friends is presented in *[Big Omega and Big Omicron and Big Theta](http://www.phil.uu.nl/datastructuren/09-10/knuth_big_omicron.pdf)* (1976) by D.E. Knuth.

Comment: @SaraWinslet: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-)